# Running Intern with React Prop-Types?

Tags: reactjs, enzyme, intern, react-proptypes

I am trying to move my team to 15.6.1 of React. As such, `prop-types` are now a separate package. Currently, when running Intern tests with Enzyme, it fails to execute because of the following:

```
Running "intern:runner" (intern) task
SUITE ERROR
Error: Module name "factoryWithTypeCheckers" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded
  at makeError  <node_modules/requirejs/require.js:165:17>
  at Object.localRequire [as require]  <node_modules/requirejs/require.js:1429:44>
  at requirejs  <node_modules/requirejs/require.js:1791:24>
  at <prop-types@15.5.10/factory.js:16:15>
```

The only thing I have done so far is add `prop-types` as a mapping in our `base.js` package as such:

`{ name: "prop-types", location: "node_modules/prop-types", main: 'prop-types'},`

I have to assume that Facebook does not intend to break test runners with this change, so there is something clearly wrong with what I am doing and I am missing it. Would someone mind pointing me in the right direction?